# The benefit or difference in Page Object techniques

Tags: angularjs, protractor, end-to-end

I would like to know if there is a benefit or difference in using one approach of page object definition versus the other:

Page Object Technique 1:

```
titlePageHeader: { get: function () { return element.all(by.css('h3.panel-title')).get(0); }},
homeIcon: { get: function () { return element(by.css('a[title="Home"]')); }},
menuIcon: { get: function () { return element(by.css('i.md.md-menu')); }},
```

Page Object Technique 2:

```
this.getTitlePageHeader = element.all(by.css('h3.panel-title')).get(0);
this.homeIcon = element(by.css('a[title="Home"]'));
this.menuIcon = element(by.css('i.md.md-menu'));
```

Comment: I think this is somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466489/canonical-way-to-define-page-objects-in-protractor. A new guide should come out soon, stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks Alec. I guess one returns a function the other a promise. I don't know if that is the focus of the guide but i would like to know since we are debating that now.

Answer (score 0):

As a [ElementFinder](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder) isn't evaluated until an action is performed on it, there is no benefit of using getters to regular variables. I would go with the latter alternative as it feels more familiar.

> An ElementFinder does not actually attempt to find the element until an action is called, which means they can be set up in helper files before the page is available. [1](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder)